# How do I learn to verify that user input is sane?

Tags: language-agnostic, user-input, verify

I'm not sure of the terminology here, so let me specify that when I say "verify" user input, I mean watch out for users claiming 30 Feb 2021 as their birthdays, rather than guarding against injection attacks.

Are there any guides to doing this correctly, or lists of common ways people do it wrong? Strategies for ensuring correct input even before it's entered (e.g., picking out of a calendar instead of typing into a text field)?

Note that I am not interested in language-specific answers (e.g., ASP.NET Validation Controls) but rather general strategies and principles.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is *input validation*.

As you point out if you use a control where it is impossible to enter invalid data you can help the client, but you still need to implement proper validation on the server.

> I mean watch out for users claiming 30 Feb 2021 as their birthdays, rather than guarding against injection attacks

Why not do both? Is there a specific reason why you want to leave yourself open to injection attacks?

Assume that the user sends a string to the server, either one they entered themselves or else one that was sent by a control you placed on the page. The first part is to find a library function for parsing the string into typed data. In your example you could use `DateTime.TryParse` to parse a string to a date. This will fail for your given example as the given date is invalid. If you cannot find a library function for what you are trying to parse you can try to write a parser yourself. For simple validations you may be able to express it as a regular expression. For more complicated inputs you may need to write some code that performs the validation, perhaps even using a parser library to help you if the input language is particularly complicated.

The second part is to implement business validation rules specific for your needs. For example you know that a birth date must be in the past, but not *too* far in the past. This will require some judgement as it's not impossible that someone using your site could be 100 years old, but it's highly unlikely that they are 200 years old since no-one is believed to be this old.

Comment: I should also guard against injection, yes, but there's lots of good advice on, e.g., parameterized SQL queries. For this question, I'm specifically interested in what you call "business validation rules". And, for that purpose, I was wondering whether there were any standard things to check, because I can't possibly have the only project that asks users for their dates of birth, etc. I would love a giant list of various kinds of question and tips on what kind of garbage users are likely to give in response.

Answer (score 0):

The freer you make the input field, the more you have to check.  Some languages may make it easy for you to verify that a text field is a valid date; others may not.

Then again, some users will resent clicking on a calendar control or three drop-downs to enter their birthdate.  They may prefer to just type it in.  That's a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend using a design pattern called "strategy". this is one of the patterns created by "the gang of four", or "gof" for short. there are some copies and variants of this pattern that you may have heard of, e.g. "inversion of control" and "dependency injection".

anyways, for an object oriented language, what you do is that you create a class called "validator", which validates data in a method called "validate". you'll have to make validate accept some relevant form of input, or overload it to have different methods for different sorts of data. or if you have access to some form of generics, you can use that.

next up, the constructor of this class should take a "validatorstrategy" object as argument. and then the actual validation will be passed through the strategy object.

to take this even further, you could then create some sort of input form generator system, where you specify input fields with your own type names. these will then generate different input fields depending on your front end language (html/android xml/java swing), and they will also affect the way in which the input is validated.

hmm.. i wonder how to solve the issue with two password input fields that need to have the exact same content to validate. how would this look in the form generating system? maybe there would be one input type named "password" which would generate one input field which doesn't show the input and has no validation, and another type named "passwordsetter" which would generate two input fields which doesn't show the input, and has the validation strategy of comparing the data from th two fields. creating that validation strategy could be pretty tricky though D: